# When using Extjs MVC,how to acquire the selections(CheckboxModel) in the controller?

Tags: extjs

Details:
In panel(View) I set selModel ：

```
this.selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',{
        listeners:{
            selectionchange: function (sm,selections){
                Ext.getCmp('removeButton').setDisabled(selections.length===0);
            }
        },
        mode:'MULTI'
    });
```

The target is delelte the item that was checked
In controller I wrote a func :

```
remove:function(){
     var view = Ext.widget('userlist');
     selection = view.selModel.getSelection();

     var store = this.getUsersStore();
     if(selection){
        store.remove(selection);
        store.sync();
     }else{
        alert('failed!');
     }
}
```

I just can't acqurice the “selection”,anything wrong?

Comment: `Ext.widget()` creates a new instance. You need to get a reference to your grid. Have a look at the controller `refs` config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.widget` creates a new component, it is not a method to retrieve a reference to a previously created component.
There are several ways to get a reference, [Ext.getCmp](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp), [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery), or using [refs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs) in your controller config

Comment: sorry,forgot to say "userlist" is already exists,it's the view page.`alias:'widget.userlist`